# Google Cloud SDK - Is there a way to manually install google cloud sdk on Linux without internet access?

Tags: linux, proxy, google-cloud-platform, failed-installation, gcloud

I am trying to install Google Cloud SDK on a Linux machine without any Internet access.

I am following the instructions at: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/?hl=en

I downloaded the tar file on my local machine and transferred it to the Linux machine using scp. I then ran the install.sh file and got the following error:

```
[me@user google-cloud-sdk]$ ./install.sh
Welcome to the Google Cloud SDK!

To help improve the quality of this product, we collect anonymized data on how
the SDK is used. You may choose to opt out of this collection now (by choosing
'N' at the below prompt), or at any time in the future by running the following
command:
    gcloud config set --scope=user disable_usage_reporting true

Do you want to help improve the Google Cloud SDK (Y/n)?  n


This will install all the core command line tools necessary for working with
the Google Cloud Platform.

/home/me/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/cli.py:661: DeprecationWarning: BaseException.message has been deprecated as of Python 2.6
  exc_message = getattr(exc, 'message', None)
/home/me/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/cli.py:664: DeprecationWarning: BaseException.message has been deprecated as of Python 2.6
  msg = u'({0}) {1}'.format(command_path_string, exc.message)
ERROR: (gcloud.components.update) Failed to fetch component listing from server. Check your network settings and try again.
```

I have a proxy server that I can use to access the internet from this Linux machine. I tried running install.sh as 'sh install.sh --proxy host:port' but obviously, there is no input parameter called proxy to install.sh.

How can I work around this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How to fix it on Windows?
`set HTTPS_PROXY=...` does not work

Answer (score 2):

Exported my proxy details as "export https_proxy='...'" before running the install.sh file.

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Advanced System settings and create a variable `HTTPS_PROXY`,
restart CMD.

```
echo %HTTPS_PROXY%
```

To make sure it has taken the changes into account. 
Launch the `install.bat`